# what is the remainder when $(17^{3}+19^{3} + 21^{3}+23^{3})$ is divided by 83?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

what is the remainder when $(17^{3}+19^{3} + 21^{3}+23^{3})$ is divided by 83?

NOTE:$a^{3}+b^{3}=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$

Comment: compute the remainders of the summands separately and add them up.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 1):

$(17^{3}+19^{3} + 21^{3}+23^{3})=(17^{3}+23^{3}+19^{3}+21^{3})$

$(17^{3}+23^{3}+19^{3}+21^{3})=((17+23)(17^{2}-17*23+23^{2})+(19+21)(19^{2}-19*21+21^{2})$

$=(40)((17+23)^{2}-3*17*23)+(40)((19+21)^{2}-3*19*21)$

$=(40)(((40)^{2}-3*17*23)+((40)^{2}-3*19*21))$

$=(40)(2*(40)^{2}-3*(17*23+19*21))$

$=(40)(2*40^{2}-3*((20-3)*(20+3)+(20-1)*(20+1)))$

$=(40)(2*40^{2}-3*((400-9)+(400-1)))$

$=(40)(2*40^{2}-3*(800-10))$

$=(80)(40^{2}-3*(400-5))$

$=(80)(1600-1200+15)$

$=(80)(400+15)$

$=(80)(5)(80+3)$

$=(80)(5)(83)$

Answer (score 1):

For every $a$, $(a+1)^3+(a-1)^3=2(a^3+3a)$ and $(a+3)^3+(a-3)^3=2(a^3+3\cdot9a)$ hence $s(a)=(a-3)^3+(a-1)^3+(a+1)^3+(a+3)^3$ is
$$
s(a)=4a^3+2\cdot3\cdot(1+9)a=4a(a^2+15).
$$
Since $83$ is prime, $83$ divides $s(a)$ if and only if $83$ divides $a$ or $83$ divides $a^2+15$. In your post, $a=20$, then $83$ does not divide $a$ but $a^2+15=415=5\cdot83$ hence $83$ divides $s(20)$.